# text from JSpinner to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, gettext, jtextarea, jspinner

How can I transfer text from a `JSpinner` to a `JTextArea`? I thought about `.getText();` but it's not working.

```
dobDate = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel(today, null, null,Calendar.MONTH));
dateEdit = new JSpinner.DateEditor(dobDate, "dd/MM/yy");
dobDate.setEditor(dateEdit);
dobDate.setBounds(215,270, 120, 25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) you can use [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#getValue%28%29).  From [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) you can use [`insert()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) or [`append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @DenisNurasy, should be sorted out (that down vote on your question is a mystery to me)